# pushing modal view controller swift

Tags: swift, modal-dialog, push, viewcontroller

I have a scene as navigation controller --> VC1 --> VC2 --> VC3. I want to modally present VC2 as well as push it to the  navigation stack. Is there any way?

Comment: Can you include the reason you want to do that? There may be a better solution than the one your asking for since UX wise, it sounds really weird.

Comment: Hi clever, I have segmented control and then a container which is connected to navigation controller. so when i display VC2  as a push view controller it gets displayed under the segmented control. if i present it modally, it does display over full screen(thats how i want) but is not getting connected to VC3. thats the reason i want VC2  to get displayed as modally but still get pushed to stack. Thanks for your help.